# Adding style Smarty

Tags: styles, smarty, prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to edit blocktopmenu on Prestashop, but I don't know where to apply my personal class. 
I don't know what file to edit and where do add my class.
I tryied to edit blocktopmenu.tpl, but I dont know what to edit.
I created my personal class on superfish-modified.css with my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is you can overide the css directly in the global.css you can add class to the blocktopmenu.tpl just like a normal html file.